# On the sum of the reciprocals of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is well known that whenever $\rho$ is a nontrivial zero of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, then $1-\rho$ is also a zero.

But does the equality $\Re \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{\rho} = \Re \sum_{\rho} \dfrac{1}{1-\rho}$ hold, where each zero is paired with its conjugate and $\rho$ runs over the entire set of nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ ?

Comment: Do you know whether or not those series converge?

Comment: Yes, infact $ \sum_{\rho} 1/\rho$ is well known to be approximately $0.023...$, where eah $\rho$ is paired with its conjugate.

Comment: The order of the summation is critical. If you pick a different order you'll possibly get a different answer. If the series doesn't converge absolutely then your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: @User1 : your two sums have exactly the same definition (definition that you didn't understand) so yes they are equal

Comment: ''..a definition that i didn't understand'', i find this comment not so helpful, because if you saw that i didn't ''understand'' the definition, why didn't you explain it ?

Answer (score 1):

If the conjugate of $\rho$ is $1-\rho$, and if by 
$$\sum_\rho \frac{1}{\rho}\tag{1}$$
you mean to pair each zero with its conjugate, then by $(1)$ you really mean
$$ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho} + \frac{1}{1 - \rho}.$$
This is precisely the same as your second sum, which is precisely
$$ \sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{1 - \rho} + \frac{1}{\rho}.$$
So your two sums are exactly the same sum.